# Bootstrap text align in label tag

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Hi i was trying to align the text on left inside the a label tag but I'm not able to do it right . See below sample code and output

```html
<div class="row form-inline" ">
    <label for="colFormLabelSm" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label col-form-label-sm text-left">Branches</label>
    <textarea class="col-sm-8 form-control form-control-sm" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="2"></textarea>
    </div>
```

[image]

See Branches that it was algin in center i like to align it in left.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Running the provided  code generates another result than described in your problem, maybe you are overwriting these settings by other code used. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/077nnadm/

Comment: because i use bootstrap . btw thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to add an extra class named "justify-content-start" to the label.
It seems like the label is getting a `justify-content: center` style from `.form-inline label`

```
<div class="row form-inline"> 
    <label for="colFormLabelSm" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label col-form-label-sm text-left justify-content-start">
      Branches
    </label>
    <textarea class="col-sm-8 form-control form-control-sm " id="exampleFormControlTextarea1 " rows="2"></textarea> 
</div>
```